# Как можно в asp.net сделать ссылку на input?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Я хочу чтобы выбор куда отправляется форма зависит, от выбранного input radio.
Но когда я делаю через jquery "$('input[name=simulators-tabs1]:checked').val()" пишет ошибку. А как правильно вписать место "ChangeTraining" название выбранного input radio?

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("ChangeTraining", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "simulators" }))
```